# Русский язык, добавление элементов в начало списка, распознание

Tags: c#

1. Как заставить программу читать русский язык? Русские ссылки типа: D:\Картинки\kinopoisk.ru-Jesse-Eisenberg-1756439.jpg читать никак не хочет.
2. Как в коде ниже заставить добавляться элементы в списке не в конец, а в начало?
3. Как распознать в тексте, что это ссылка на файл? То есть он должен принять вид C:/asd/asd, но не должен "gdag".

-

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load("C:/q.xml");
    for (int s = 1; s <= 9; s++)
    {
        var vv = xDocument.Element("start").Element("s" + s).Value;

        if (vv != "")
        {
           contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(vv);
           //this.contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(new ToolStripButton("ASD22",null, ));
        }
    }
    this.contextMenuStrip1.ItemClicked += new ToolStripItemClickedEventHandler(contextMenuStrip1_ItemClicked);
}
```

Comment: Первое решил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2.`contextMenuStrip1.Items.Insert(0, vv);`

3.`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex`

Comment: Огромнейшнее спасибо! Вот только где объявлять третье?

Comment: Первый параметр Process.Start - это путь к исполняемому файлу, второй - аргументы командной строки через пробел. Если они сами содержат пробелы, такие аргументы надо брать в кавычки.

Comment: Кстати, а для проверки, что строка - это ссылка на файл, можете попробовать `System.IO.File.Exists`. Если метод не упал и вернул true, то это ссылка на файл. Пожалуй, это проще, чем через регулярные выражения.

Comment: С проверкой разобрался. Осталось понять, как объявлять элементы в начало списка. Так и не понял как это делается.